# Import script will not update State field

Tags: clearquest

I am exporting information from one CQ database to update information in another CQ database.  I am doing this via a PERL script which utilizes a AdminModify action which opens all field for edit.  All fields except the State field which is my issue.  I tried to switch from the AdminModify action to a Import action but I get the same result.  ClearQuest will not let me bypass their state matrix rules and update the State field automatically.  Has anyone encountered this issue or have an idea to get around it?  All I can think of is to code the heck out of this and have the script jump through each state....that's ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Is this really what you want to do? ClearQuest lets you define hooks which can perform additional actions that might have other effects that aren't copied over if you were to just copy fields (including state) from one record in a database to another record in a different database. So to jump from state A to D, you might not be doing the same thing as if you went from A to B to C and finally to D.

Perhaps what you should do is have an audit-trail like log that keeps track of each action and which fields were changed then replay those in the other CQ database when you want to 'sync' the records.

Aside from that, the only way to change the state outside of a state transition action is to run a SQL command on the database to change the state. You could use the pdsql command to connect to the database and run the SQL.

Comment: Adam, you answered a question for me on the IBM CQ forums related to multiline text field max length.  Thank you!  I agree with your solution above and found out from IBM that there is no flag or secret command that will let me bypass the integrity checks when changing states.  My issue is that our production database is on one very exclusive network.  This network cannot be accessed except by logging into protected machines from within the firewall.  However, our users want another instance of our CQ database to report on from our open network.

Comment: I am currently exporting data and then importing into the reporting database via a script which is scheduled on CRON.  I am also walking the records through their states via script but it's painful.  But if I want to avoid corrupting records and stay in CQ harmony then I guess I need to push everything through the CQ business logic.  Thanks for your help and suggestions.